# html5 in html4 browsers, giving an id to head tag

Tags: html, browser

I'd like to put an id on me `<head>` tag however I read from this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) :

> In HTML5, the id attribute can be used on any HTML element (it will
>   validate on any HTML element. However, it is not necessarily useful).
>
> In HTML 4.01, the id attribute cannot be used with: base, head,
>   html, meta, param, script, style, and title.

I'm failing to understand what the above implies exactly.
I've tested on IE8 (from the dev tool compatibility mode, not real ie8) and I see an id attribute `<HEAD id=head>`.

So what exactly do they mean with *illegal* ? What happens if I use HTML5 in a HTML4 browser such as ie8 ? Am I gonna have malformed document errors left and right ?

For example I tried article in IE 8. It was rendered but it was rendered twice.
So does that mean that the behavior is simply erratic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's illegal according to the DTD, so attempting to validate a head element with an id attribute as HTML 4 will result in errors. However this is not enforced by any known DOM implementations.

article is an HTML5 element, which IE8 is known *not* to support out of the box so you will see issues like that. That said, generally any behavior that involves *unsupported* markup can be considered to be erratic. HTML5 relaxes the restriction on the id attribute simply because there was no reason for the restriction to be there, and again as mentioned, it just happens that it was never enforced anyway.